# how to evenly center image and text on the page

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to put 3 sections of images and text at the center of the page. I've tried display flex align-items to center, and justify-content to center. justify-content to puts everything to the center of the page, but everything is uneven.

Here is my code

```css
.contact-main-container{
    max-height: 100vw;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    color: #e0e7ff;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.contact-links-container{
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.contact-link{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.contact-link img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div className="contact-main-container">
  <header>
    <h1>Contact Me</h1>
  </header>
  <div className="contact-links-container">
    <section className="contact-link">
      <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/google/google-original.svg" />
      <a>rsteward117@gmail.com</a>
    </section>
    <section className="contact-link">
      <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/github/github-original.svg" />
      <a>Github</a>
    </section>
    <section className="contact-link">
      <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/linkedin/linkedin-original.svg" />
      <a>Linkedin</a>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using reactjs?

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you use `className` your HTML has to be `class` instead of `className`. Try to make your html with `class` then works fine your code.

I don't know which kind of center you want, so I had put 2 snippets.

Here is your updated snippet to be,

### Snippet 1 : icons in Vertical

```css
.contact-main-container{
    max-height: 100vw;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    color: #e0e7ff;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.contact-links-container{
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.contact-link{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.contact-link img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-main-container">
  <header>
    <h1>Contact Me</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="contact-links-container">
    <section class="contact-link">
      <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/google/google-original.svg" />
      <a>rsteward117@gmail.com</a>
    </section>
    <section class="contact-link">
      <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/github/github-original.svg" />
      <a>Github</a>
    </section>
    <section class="contact-link">
      <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/linkedin/linkedin-original.svg" />
      <a>Linkedin</a>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Snippet 2 : icons in Horizontal

```css
.contact-main-container{
    max-height: 100vw;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    color: #e0e7ff;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.contact-links-container{
    border: solid 1px black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.contact-link{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    flex-direction:column;
    width:100%
}

.contact-link img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom:10px
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-main-container">
  <header>
    <h1>Contact Me</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="contact-links-container">
    <section class="contact-link">
      <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/google/google-original.svg" />
      <a>rsteward117@gmail.com</a>
    </section>
    <section class="contact-link">
      <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/github/github-original.svg" />
      <a>Github</a>
    </section>
    <section class="contact-link">
      <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/linkedin/linkedin-original.svg" />
      <a>Linkedin</a>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was using react I forget to mention my bad.

Comment: ok, then if browser will automatic convert to class instead of className. then apply above css then I think it should works.

Answer (score 1):

the default direction of flexbox is row
you should define in ".contact-link" class:
flex-direction: column;

```css
.contact-main-container{
    max-height: 100vw;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    color: #e0e7ff;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.contact-links-container{
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.contact-link{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.contact-link img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="contact-main-container">
        <header>
          <h1>Contact Me</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="contact-links-container">
          <section class="contact-link">
                <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/google/google-original.svg" />
                <a>rsteward117@gmail.com</a>
          </section>
          <section class="contact-link">
            <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/github/github-original.svg" />
            <a>Github</a>
          </section>
          <section class="contact-link">
            <img src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/linkedin/linkedin-original.svg" />
            <a>Linkedin</a>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
```